# Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o90.fit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I want to apply random forest algorithm over a dataframe consisting of three columns namely JournalID, IndexedJournalID(Obtained using StringIndexer of Spark) and feature vector. I used below code to read the dataframe from parquet file and apply String Indexer over JournalID column to convert it to categorical type.

```py
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
from pyspark.ml.feature import IndexToString, StringIndexer, VectorIndexer
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.linalg import VectorUDT

df=spark.read.parquet('JouID-UBTFIDFVectors-server22.parquet')
labelIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="journalid", outputCol="IndexedJournalID")

labelsDF=labelIndexer.fit(df)
df1=labelsDF.transform(df)

# This function converts sparse vectors to dense vectors....I applied this on raw features column to convert them to VectorUDT type.....
parse_ = udf(lambda l: Vectors.dense(l), VectorUDT())

df2 = df1.withColumn("featuresNew", parse_(df1["features"])).drop('features')
```

New Dataframe Schema(df2) is as follows:

```
root
 |-- journalid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- indexedLabel: double (nullable = false)
 |-- featuresNew: vector (nullable = true)
```

Then I split df2 into training and test set and create object of random forest classifier as below:

```py
(trainingData, testData) = df2.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2])
rf = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol="indexedLabel", featuresCol="featuresNew", numTrees=2 )
```

Finally apply fit() method over trainingData obtained above.

```py
rfModel=rf.fit(trainingData)
```

With this  I am able to train model on 100 instances of input dataframe. However,over whole training data, this line gives following error.

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 53652)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/sntps/code/conda3/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 317, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/data/sntps/code/conda3/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 348, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/data/sntps/code/conda3/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/data/sntps/code/conda3/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/data/sp/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 235, in handle
    num_updates = read_int(self.rfile)
  File "/data/sp/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 685, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError
----------------------------------------
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/sp/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1159, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/sp/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 985, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/data/sp/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1164, in send_command
    "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:41060)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/sntps/code/conda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-10-46d7488961c7>", line 1, in <module>
    rfModel=rf.fit(trainingData)
  File "/data/sp/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/base.py", line 132, in fit
    return self._fit(dataset)
  File "/data/sp/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 288, in _fit
    java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
  File "/data/sp/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 285, in _fit_java
    return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
  File "/data/sp/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/data/sp/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/data/sp/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 336, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name))
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o90.fit

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/sntps/code/conda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1828, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'Py4JError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/sp/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 929, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
.(traceback...not writing due to space issue)
.
.  
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o90.fit
```

This error is not very descriptive and hence it has become difficult for me to identify the where I am going wrong. Any help would help a lot.

Input Description:
Input Dataframe Contains 2696512 rows and each row's feature vector is of 262144 length.

Answer (score 2):

After going through lot of related questions on stackoverflow , I thought this may be happening because of running this in jupyter-notebook. So later I ran it on commandline using spark-submit script and I am not getting this error anymore. I don't know though why this error is popping up if I run this in jupyter-notebook.

Comment: I am getting similar issue in Jupyter notebook for lda.fit()